# Html 5 Collision Between Points on an Arc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I'm working on a game that uses projectiles and a shielding system. The player would hold down 'Space' to use the shield. My plan is to get the projectiles to bounce of of the enemies shields (I've implemented speed so I already know how to do that). The problem I am having is with the collision, since the player rotates to follow the mouse I struggled with finding the best way to create the shield but I eventually settled on an arc, I used some trigonometry to get the left, leftHalf, mid, rightHalf, and right point of the arc/shield. [The Player with Shield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5aRt.png). The issue is I can't get the collision to work from just 5, x/y coordinates (the arc is just being drawn for show I'm only sending the points to the server). This is what I have for my collision so far: 
**p**: Player object
**self**: bullet object
**bot**: a variable based on the direction the character is facing (bottom: true or false)
**shieldLeft, sheildRight, etc**: an array containing x and y coordinate 0 for x, 1 for y

```
if (self.getDistance(p) < 32 && self.parent !== p.id)
        {
            if (p.isShielding == true)
            {

                switch(self.bot)
                {
                    case true:
                        if (self.x >= p.shieldRight[0] && self.x <= p.shieldLeft[0])
                        {
                            console.log("BOT X");
                            if ((self.y >= p.shieldLeft[1] || self.y >= p.shieldRight[1]) && self.y <= p.shieldMid[1])
                            {
                                console.log("BOT Y");
                                self.spdX = -self.spdX;
                                self.spdY = -self.spdY;
                            }
                        }


                    break;
                    case false:
                        if (self.x <= p.shieldRight[0] && self.x >= p.shieldLeft[0])
                        {
                            console.log("TOP X");
                            if ((self.y <= p.shieldLeft[1] || self.y <= p.shieldRight[1]) && self.y >= p.shieldMid[1])
                            {
                                console.log("TOP Y");
                                self.spdX = -self.spdX;
                                self.spdY = -self.spdY;
                            }
                        }
                    break;
                }



            }


        }
```

I would really appreciate any help, I can't continue with the game features until there *actually* is a game. Thank you!

Comment: You need to create a fiddle perhaps so we can see it in action, hard to fully understand without a working version

Comment: I have a working version, but it's on my node.js server on my desktop. Can fiddle do that. Sorry, please forgive my ignorance I've never used it. I appreciate the fast response.

Comment: Just to be clear you're unsure how to detect if one of the projectiles is touching the shield and how to tell from which direction?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: crosshair;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
   // Anonymous closure
   (function() {
   
    // Enforce strict rules for JS code
    "use strict";
    
    // App variables
    var canvasWidth = 180;
    var canvasHeight = 160;
    var canvas = null;
    var bounds = null;
    var ctx = null;
    var player = null;
    var projectiles = [];
     projectiles.length = 5;
    
    // Classes
    
    // Constructor function
    function Player(x,y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.dx = 0.0;
     this.dy = 0.0;
     this.rotation = 0.0;
     this.targetX = 0.0;
     this.targetY = 0.0;
     this.isShieldUp = false;
     this.isShieldRecharging = false;
     this.shieldPower = this.shieldPowerMax;
     this.left = false;
     this.right = false;
     this.up = false;
     this.down = false;
     window.addEventListener("keydown",this.onkeydown.bind(this));
     window.addEventListener("keyup",this.onkeyup.bind(this));
     window.addEventListener("mousemove",this.onmousemove.bind(this));
    }
    
    // shared properties/functions across all instances
    Player.prototype = {
     width: 10,
     height: 10,
     shieldRadius: 15.0,
     shieldArcSize: 3.0, // In Radians
     shieldPowerMax: 50.0,
     shieldPowerCharge: 0.5,
     shieldPowerDrain: 0.75,
     
     onkeydown: function(e) {
      switch(e.key) {
       case " ": this.isShieldUp = true && !this.isShieldRecharging; break;
       case "w": this.up = true; break;
       case "s": this.down = true; break;
       case "a": this.left = true; break;
       case "d": this.right = true; break;
      }
     },
     
     onkeyup: function(e) {
      switch(e.key) {
       case " ": this.isShieldUp = false; break;
       case "w": this.up = false; break;
       case "s": this.down = false; break;
       case "a": this.left = false; break;
       case "d": this.right = false; break;
      }
     },
     
     onmousemove: function(e) {
      this.targetX = e.clientX - bounds.left;
      this.targetY = e.clientY - bounds.top;
     },
    
     tick: function() {
      var x = (this.targetX - this.x);
      var y = (this.targetY - this.y);
      var l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
      x = x / l;
      y = y / l;
      this.rotation = Math.acos(x) * (y < 0.0 ? -1.0 : 1.0);
      
      if (this.isShieldUp) {
       this.shieldPower = this.shieldPower - this.shieldPowerDrain;
       if (this.shieldPower < 0.0) {
        this.shieldPower = 0.0;
        this.isShieldUp = false;
        this.isShieldRecharging = true;
       }
      } else {
       this.shieldPower = this.shieldPower + this.shieldPowerCharge;
       if (this.shieldPower > this.shieldPowerMax) {
        this.shieldPower = this.shieldPowerMax;
        this.isShieldRecharging = false;
       }
      }
      
      if (this.up) { --this.y; this.dy = -1; } else
      if (this.down) { ++this.y; this.dy = 1; } else { this.dy = 0; }
      if (this.left) { --this.x; this.dx = -1; } else
      if (this.right) { ++this.x; this.dx = 1; } else { this.dx = 0; }
     },
     
     render: function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
      ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0.5 * this.height,0.0);
      ctx.lineTo(-0.5 * this.height,0.5 * this.width);
      ctx.lineTo(-0.5 * this.height,-0.5 * this.width);
      ctx.lineTo(0.5 * this.height,0.0);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      
      if (this.isShieldUp) {
       ctx.strokeStyle = "cyan";
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.arc(0.0,0.0,this.shieldRadius,this.shieldArcSize * -0.5,this.shieldArcSize * 0.5,false);
       ctx.stroke();
      }
      
      ctx.rotate(-this.rotation);
      ctx.translate(-this.x,-this.y);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(canvasWidth - 80,canvasHeight - 20,75,15);
      ctx.fillStyle = this.isShieldRecharging ? "red" : "cyan";
      ctx.fillRect(canvasWidth - 75,canvasHeight - 15,65 * (this.shieldPower / this.shieldPowerMax),5);
     }
    };
    
    function Projectile(x,y,dx,dy) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.dx = dx;
     this.dy = dy;
    }
    
    Projectile.prototype = {
     radius: 2.5,
     
     tick: function(player) {
      this.x = this.x + this.dx;
      this.y = this.y + this.dy;
      if (this.x + this.radius < 0.0) { this.x = canvasWidth + this.radius; }
      if (this.x - this.radius > canvasWidth) { this.x = -this.radius; }
      if (this.y + this.radius < 0.0) { this.y = canvasHeight + this.radius; }
      if (this.y - this.radius > canvasHeight) { this.y = -this.radius; }
      
      if (player.isShieldUp) {
       var px = (player.x - this.x);
       var py = (player.y - this.y);
       var pl = Math.sqrt(px * px + py * py);
       var ml = Math.sqrt(this.dx * this.dx + this.dy * this.dy);
       var mx = this.dx / ml;
       var my = this.dy / ml;
       px = px / pl;
       py = py / pl;
       
       if (Math.acos(px * mx + py * my) < player.shieldArcSize * 0.5 && pl < player.shieldRadius) {
        px = -px;
        py = -py;
        
        this.dx = this.dx - 2.0 * px * (this.dx * px + this.dy * py) + player.dx;
        this.dy = this.dy - 2.0 * py * (this.dx * px + this.dy * py) + player.dy;
       }
      }
     },
     
     render: function() {
      ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.radius,this.y);
      ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0.0,2.0 * Math.PI,false);
     }
    }
    
    // Game loop
    function loop() {
     // Tick
     player.tick();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < projectiles.length; ++i) {
      projectiles[i].tick(player);
     }
     // Render
     ctx.fillStyle = "#555555";
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
     player.render();
     
     ctx.fillStyle = "white";
     ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
     ctx.beginPath();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < projectiles.length; ++i) {
      projectiles[i].render();
     }
     
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();
     //
     requestAnimationFrame(loop); // Runs the loop at 60hz
    }
    
    // "Main Method", executes after the page loads
    window.onload = function() {
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     canvas.width = canvasWidth;
     canvas.height = canvasHeight;
     bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     player = new Player(90.0,80.0);
     
     for (var i = 0; i < projectiles.length; ++i) {
      projectiles[i] = new Projectile(
       Math.random() * canvasWidth,
       Math.random() * canvasHeight,
       Math.random() * 2.0 - 1.0,
       Math.random() * 2.0 - 1.0
      );
     }
     
     loop();
    }
   
   })();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate all the help everyone has given me!